Unity scene doesn't have skybox and lightsource
I am a beginner in Unity and 1st time asking in this platform. I am working as a team and I got invited to this project via Github. (if this matters at all)
I want to work in 3D environment and I chose Basic 3D(Built-in). (Am I actually in 2D?)
Overall, I am facing two problems with starting my project.
-- This scene does not have a sky and I am unable to add a Skybox. I toggled 'Skybox' and 'Scenelighting'(lightbulb icon) on, but there's no use.
-- There's no Directional Light either although it is included in the hierarchy. Hence when I add multiple objects, I can't distinguish between them since there're no shadows.
I am in Unity 2022.3.30.f1 version.
I toggled on 'Skybox' and 'Scene Lighting' --> No change.
I tried dragging my skybox in. --> Dragging doesn't work.
I shifted my Directional Light source and Main Camera in a similar position to my cube --> No change.
I tried different scene types; Basic(URP), Standard(URP), Basic 3D(Built-in). --> No change.
I AD

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

what is your specific question? ... please edit your post and add a question

You need to add the skybox to the Camera node, see the example image attached.
The Light should be added to the Scene as an object, at the top level.
Note that your image shows the Scene panel view and you should look in the Game panel for visible lighting effects.
One thing that is not obvious, if you have a skybox on a camera layer that is far away, then it may not be visible in Scene view. To make it visible you will need to edit the Scene panel camera and increase its far clip distance until it is visible, as illustrated in the first image attached.
One thing that is not obvious, if you have a skybox on a camera layer that is far away, then it may not be visible in Scene view. To make it visible you will need to edit the Scene panel camera and increase its far clip distance until it is visible, as illustrated in the second image attached.



Note that this asker seems to be using the Universal Render Pipeline, which has some slightly different settings.
